# How to deny access from a specific browser in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with an App running on NextJs (developed with ReactJS) that shouldn't be used from Internet Explorer browsers. Then, I need configure it to deny access from IE with a message to invite users to download other browser (I've this part controlled). So, how is the better way to deny access from specific browsers in NextJS?

I've tried using the navigation.userAgent function, but it didn't work for me, something like this in the _app.tsx:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla") > 0) {
        return (<GlobalWrapper>
                    <div>"Browser not supported, ok." </div>
                </GlobalWrapper>)
   }
```

Please, can you help me?

Comment: use the package [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect/blob/master/docs/selectors.md) it could help you

Comment: thanks, I'll try it and then I'll comment here.

Comment: It works! Thanks @Spring!